# Why won't IE (Edge) using my local server login correctly using Facebook and Parse

Tags: internet-explorer, parse-platform, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm developing a static website with Parse on the backend and using Facebook login.

When testing locally using IE (Edge) the following happens:

1. I click login on my website (running locally)
2. Facebook login window pops up asking for login
3. I enter my username/password press enter
4. The popup screen goes blank and stays there (it should go away and log me in)
5. My website will eventually get a timeout error

I did some googling and the only thing I can find is from a few years ago mentioning that you need SSL. But my production site doesn't use SSL and it logs in fine, so I don't think its that.

My facebook code is as follows:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  console.log('fbAsyncInit')
  Parse.FacebookUtils.init({
    appId      : '[MY FACEBOOK APP ID]', // Facebook App ID
    cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow Parse to access the session
    xfbml      : true,  // initialize Facebook social plugins on the page
    version    : 'v2.4' // point to the latest Facebook Graph API version
  });
};


(function(d, s, id){
   var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
   if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
   js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
   js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
   fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
 }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));



// NOTE: The success/error never gets called
var _loginFacebookUser = function() {
  if (ParseUtils.getCurrentUser() == null) {
    Parse.FacebookUtils.logIn(null, {
      success: function(rawFBUser) {
        if (!rawFBUser.existed()) {
          // login doesn't give us user details (e.g. name)
          // need to make a separate call for that
          _updateRawFBUserFields(rawFBUser);
          UserServerActionCreators.receiveSignup(user);
        } else {
          var user =  Raw.convertUser(rawFBUser);
          UserServerActionCreators.receiveLogin(user);
        }
        NavigationActionCreators.transitionTo('editor');
        _getSpeeches();
        _getUserState();
      },
      error: function(user, error) {
        console.log("User cancelled the Facebook login or did not fully authorize.");
      }
    });
  } else {
    NavigationActionCreators.transitionTo('editor');
  }
};
```

Comment: is the Site URL in your Facebook Developer dashboard the same as your local setup?

Comment: The auth url is? But not the site